# Mocha hangs after execution when connecting with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mocha.js

> *Talk is cheap, show me the code*
>
> Linus Torvald

Doing integration tests with `mocha` and `supertest`. Here's the code

```
//app.js
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(config.mongoURL, error => {
  if (error) {
    throw error;
  }

  console.log('Connected to mongodb');
});

modules.export = app;



// test.js
it('returns 200', () => {
  return supertest(app).get('/').expect(200);
});
```

Basically what happens is that the output "Connected to mongodb" logs after the tests are run (I have like 3 tests only, none use the db), and afterwards mocha hangs there and I have to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. I probably missed some configuration but I can't see it.

Needless to say, commenting the mongoose lines (`mongoose.connect(...)`) fixes it.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to disconnect from the database after the tests are done. This can be done in the `after` function, for example.

```js
after((done) => {
  app.close(() => {
    mongoose.connection.close(done);
  });
});
```

If you don't disconnect you'll get the symptoms you are describing.

Comment: Now this makes sense, but how come I've never seen in the tutorials? isn't there any other way to automatically cascade the SIGTERM?

Answer (score 1):

a more simplified answer

```
after((done) => {
    mongoose.connection.close(done);
});
```