# Mocha tests hang after completion when working with web3 smart contracts

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, smartcontracts, web3js

I wrote some integration tests for a node app that works with Ethereum smart contracts (and thus use the contracts' state as a data storage). I am instantiating some smart contracts interfaces using `web3` and in the assertion parts of the tests I am using them to check that valid information has been written to the blockchain.

However after the tests pass the mocha process is still running and I have to shut it down manually. I suspect this happens because the smart contract interfaces are basically open connections and they are not closed, I know it happens when you do the same with normal database connections (see here: [Mocha hangs after execution when connecting with Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48725343/mocha-hangs-after-execution-when-connecting-with-mongoose)).

I didn't find any `disconnect` or similar `web3` api methods though, anyone had any similar experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

Someone pointed me that there is an `--exit` flag that you can pass to mocha and it kills the process after all tests have finished running. This is probably a good enough solution for now.